# State-of-the-art in Collaborative Filtering

Tags: optimization, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

I am working on a project for collaborative filtering (CF), i.e. completing a partially observed matrix or more generally tensor. I am a newbie to the field, and for this project eventually I have to compare our method to other well-known ones that nowadays, proposed methods are compared against them, namely state-of-the-art in CF.

My search revealed the following methods. Indeed I came across them by looking at some of these papers and their references, or by looking at experiments section when they do comparisons. I would be happy to know for a new proposed method and to do a comparison with SoTA, which of the following would be a good pick to do so? If not among them, I would be happy to know a good representative.

Based on Matrix Factorization:

1. [Weighted Low Rank Approximation](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/SrebroJaakkolaICML03.pdf) (ICML 2003)
2. [Modeling User Rating Profiles For Collaborative Filtering](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~marlin/research/papers/urp-nips2003.pdf) (NIPS 2003)
3. [The Multiple Multiplicative Factor Model For Collaborative Filtering](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~marlin/research/papers/mmf-icml2004.ps) (ICML 2004)
4. [Fast Maximum Margin Matrix Factorization for Collaborative Prediction](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/RennieSrebroICML05.pdf) (ICML 2005)
5. [Probabilistic Matrix Factorization](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3208-probabilistic-matrix-factorization.pdf) (NIPS 2007)
6. [Bayesian Probabilistic Matrix Factorization](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~amnih/papers/bpmf.pdf) (ICML 2008)
7. [Regression-based Latent Factor Models](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1557029) (KDD 2009)
8. [Non-linear Matrix Factorization with Gaussian Processes](http://www.machinelearning.org/archive/icml2009/papers/384.pdf) (ICML 2009)
9. [Dynamic Poission Factorization](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~lcharlin/papers/2015_CharlinRanganathMcInerneyBlei.pdf) (ACM Conference on Recommender Systems 2015)

Based on Tensor Factorization:

1. [Incorporating Contextual Information in Recommender Systems Using a Multidimensional Approach](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.423.5495&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (ACM Transactions on Information Systems (TOIS) 2005)
2. [Bayesian Probabilistic Tensor Factorization](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jgc/publication/PublicationPDF/Temporal_Collaborative_Filtering_With_Bayesian_Probabilidtic_Tensor_Factorization.pdf) (SIAM Data Mining 2010)
3. [Low-rank tensor completion by Riemannian optimization](http://sma.epfl.ch/~anchpcommon/publications/tensorcompletion.pdf) (BIT Numerical Mathematics 54.2 (2014))

Comment: A tensor for continuous data? Mixed data? Categorical data? Since you don't say, maybe we can assume continuous. David Dunson's *Bayesian Tensor Regression* is an approach for tensor contingency tables that might provide some insight or guidance -- but it's not an RS approach.  http://www.researchgate.net/publication/282181971_Bayesian_Tensor_Regression    Also, check out the papers on his website at Duke U.

Comment: You may also consider nonnegative matrix factorization (NMF).

Comment: Your list seems reasonable, I also would add methods based on neural networks. There's a survey paper that is a good place to start: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.07435.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can also take a look on the [Gravity Recommendation System](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/KDD-cup-2007/proceedings/gravity-Tikk.pdf) (GRS) paper, which is also about Matrix Factorization. The authors competed using this algorithm in the well known Netflix Prize.